# Suspending a thread in a wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I have a WPF application in which i have this class :

```
public partial class Global : UserControl
    {
        public static List<Thread> listofthreads = new List<Thread>();
        public Global()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           Thread windowThread = new Thread(delegate() { verifing(); });
           listofthreads.Add(windowThread);
            windowThread.Start();

        }

        public void verifing()
        {
            if (Global2.Pat_pathregfile.Length > 5 && Global2.Pat_pathcalibfile.Length > 5) {
                if (utilisation.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                {
                    utilisation.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {

                    utilisation.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
                    {
                        utilisation.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }));

                }
                foreach (Thread t in listofthreads) {
                    try
                    {
                        t.Suspend();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }

            }
            else {
                if (utilisation.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                {
                    utilisation.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                }
                else
                {

                    utilisation.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
                    {
                        utilisation.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    }));

                }
                Thread windowThread = new Thread(delegate() { verifing(); });
                windowThread.Start();
                listofthreads.Add(windowThread);
            }

        }


    }
```

i need to kill `properly` all of the threads that i have used

```
 foreach (Thread t in listofthreads) {
                        try
                        {
                            t.Suspend();
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
```

But the program indicates that the use of the method `suspend` isn't recommended .

1. Why?
2. It seems that some threads is still working even after the close of the windows, Why this happens? How can i fix it?
3. Is another method of killing a thread exist in wpf?

Comment: `Suspend` method has been marked obsolete. You should use [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) instead to synchronize threads.

Comment: Better explain, what are you trying to achieve. Your play with threads and setting of the `Visibility` suggests, that you're doing things wrong way. Are you trying to perform some kind of validation?

Comment: You don't want to suspend a thread. You want to put a thread into a wait state, or signal the thread to terminate itself. But you don't want to suspend, nor do you want to kill a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Why?

`Suspend` method has been marked as `Obsolete` by [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Error states itself:

> Thread.Suspend has been deprecated.  Please use other classes in
>   System.Threading, such as Monitor, Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to
>   synchronize Threads or protect resources.

---

> 2) It seems that some threads is still working even after the close of
>   the windows, Why this happens? How can i fix it?

You have started all threads as `foreground thread` which won't stop automatically when main thread finishes its execution. In case you want to stop all threads once all foreground threads stops, you should mark thread as `background thread`.

```
windowThread.IsBackground = true;
```

---

> 3) Is another method of killing a thread exist in wpf?

Use [Thread.Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b50fdsz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, closing your main thread will automatically stop all background threads (*IsBackground set to true on thread*), you should not worry about killing them.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? You are creating threads just for the purpose of checking some condition? And when the condition is true, you change the visibility and block all threads(!) from further execution. And when the condition is not true, you create another thread that does the same. Why are you suspending all threads (including the active one) instead of just letting it terminate? And if you want to periodically check for a condition, use a timer or a wait event instead.

Just as a side note: Your foreach-loops will eventually throw `InvalidOperationException`, because you're changing the collection without a lock.

And then, don't try to kill threads. Use flags or signals instead. Any attempt to kill threads is a) bad design and b) prone to errors and unexpected behavior.

Comment: You said `Why are you suspending all threads (including the active one) instead of just letting it terminate` : i need the thread be infine until the condition is true

Comment: Your thread will either never end or end immediately (and spawn a new one). You need to add a loop inside your thread if you want to wait for a condition. Your code is _far_ to complicated for what you're trying to achieve. Besides that you're doing multi-thread-busy-waiting. Use one thread with a loop or, better yet, raise a signal when the condition changes.

Comment: Thanks @PMF and @Rohit Vats : your way is better than mine. I added the loop inside the thread and i make it `windowThread.IsBackground = true;` so i get a good result :)